# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Sometimes in my tests on my localhost I´m having this error:

**Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded**

And I dont see what can be wrong.

The error points to this code below, that is my connection code and the error message points specifically **for this line**:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$dbName};host={$dbHost}", $dbUser, $dbPass);
```

Do you see something that may be giving me this error? Because for me everything seems fine!

**My php file for the connection to DB**:

```
<?php
function forConnect() {
  $dbHost = 'localhost';
  $dbUser = 'root';
  $dbPass = '';
  $dbName = 'my_site';    
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$dbName};host={$dbHost}", $dbUser, $dbPass);
  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
  return $pdo;
}
?>
```

Comment: And other thing strange on my localhost tests is that the connections are really very slow.. I don´t not know if can have something to do also with this maximum execution error!

Comment: What application are you using for your virtual server? I prefer wamp because it's faster than EasyPHP.

Comment: Xampp!! I have now again the error! IT becomes a bit impossible work like this! Do you think that is/can be a problem of xampp?

Comment: It can be. I haven't had Xampp, but I personally had both EasyPHP and Wamp, and Wamp was truly faster (like 10 times) when it came to working with database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your database connections are really slow, you will time out. You can increase your max execution time setting in PHP to see if the connection is slow or not getting established at all. Depending on your setup, there may be a firewall rule or some such intercepting the connection request which would then cause a timeout.